# Newsletter gmail remove share button

Tags: html, css, gmail, newsletter

I've created a news letter, but when I see it in gmail there is a white frame when I hover over an image and a "Share" button appers like so:
[image]

Does anyone knows how can I remove this frame and share button in gmail when creating my news letter.

Here is the code that im using to create this newsletter:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body style="background:#a13022;" align="center">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="myImg.gif"/></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @samankhademi I cant send u the newsletter its for a client, you can see the issue just open an email where you have a image in it

Comment: how create newsletter software or template share code

Comment: @samankhademi question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is to not use ThunderBird to send email - because thunderbird scans emails before sending them(using avast in my example) that adds borders around images. This is not heppening when using MailChimp for example.

Answer (score 1):

by default google set css for element e.g tr have margin
try this

```
<table align="center">
     <tr>
        <td><a href="#" target="_blank" style="border:0px none !important;"><img src="myImg.gif" style="border:0px none !important;"/></a></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: check what's element have this frame

Answer (score 1):

This is unusual - I don't get the share link at all when using href'd image links. My image code usually looks something like this:

```
<a href=""><img alt="" src="" width="" height="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"></a>
```

There are slight differences in what I use to what you use, so try that out. maybe the `border:0;` might suppress it (probably not, but I've seen stranger things in html email). It could be the target attribute you are using also.

If that doesn't solve it, it is probably a plugin you have or maybe a Google+ thing. Check where the share button is linking to - it might reveal the answer.

Comment: Nope not working either - when i hover over an image i can see that `class="GH"` is added to the image

Comment: What version of Gmail (app vs browser) are you using? Does this happen in both, or just one? I really think it is a plugin or browser extension doing it...

Comment: Im experiencing the issue in browser - not tryed in app

Comment: Try another browser to see if it is in all browsers, or just one. If it is in just one, you probably have an extension causing it.

Comment: Nope same issue in Firefox and in Chrome.